# Сокеты и аутентификация

Tags: node.js, аутентификация, socket.io, сокет

Добрвй день!

У меня есть небольшой сервер на node.js, позволяющий просматривать онлайн состояние соревнований: по usb подключен arduino, который считает время, круги и т. д. Собственно, я в цикле слушаю usb порт, когда оттуда приходит сообщение — запускается какая-то логика, в результате которой клиентам через сокет посылается какая-то информация.

Так вот, теперь мне хочется нормальный инструмент контроля этой штуки. Я себе это представляю так: есть страничка, на которой админ введет пароль и через те же сокеты будет посылать команды на сервер, к примеру «сбросить таймер у arduino и начать соревнование заново» и т. д. Только не ясно, как делать аутентификацию через сокеты. Есть ли готовые инструменты? Прийдется посылать с каждым сообщением еще и сессию? Как такое делается у нормальных людей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У веб-сокета устанавливается connection, канал связи на весь период жизни соединения. При установке соединения нужно провести авторизацию: тот же ввод на клиенте пары логин/пароль, и если она прошла проверку на сервере -- то установленное соединение считается доверенным до его обрыва или до истечения какого-то таймаута.

Comment: А можно пример кода? Я теперь не уверен, что понимаю, как работает серверная часть socket.io.
По идее:

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
     var authenticated = false; // эта переменная будет жить до окончания жизни соединения?
     socket.on('auth', function (data) {
      if (...) {authenticated = true;}
     // Так можно делать?
    });

Comment: @deivan, вот еще по ходу вопрос возник: я понимаю, как отправлять сообщение от одного клиента всем остальным. Но я хочу отправлять не от имени клиента, а от сервера. К примеру в чатике все понятно: вот пользователь user_1 пишет всем «привет». И происходит где-то в уникальном классе для этого user_1 какое-то событие. Но ведь в моем случае все иначе: какая-то функция получает информацию, что время круга — 28 секунд. Как ее теперь отправлять всем? Ну не создавать же для этого отдельный экземпляр класса socket? (это тот, что присылается в on('connection'))

Comment: @Zelta `io.sockets.emit('message', {content: "Hello World"});`

Comment: @Zelta, все правильно понимаете, удачи!